# Paypal cannot process payments on sandbox from the vault credit card

Tags: paypal

I can successfully use the vault card process. I am using the credit card from my vault.

ENDPOINT: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
RESPONSE: Internal service error

Comment: Your question does not contain much useful information. Could you add more information such as the API payload, the response etc? Also, you might want to avoid using generic test credit card number (such as 4111111111111111) because PayPal would reject such test credit card number.

Comment: In addition, you might want to check the JSON payload in the API to make sure it is in correct format

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by finding other test credit card numbers. It appears that Paypal's test card numbers were overused that's why it returned that 'Internal service' or sometimes 'Unknown' error. Thanks for giving your thoughts regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by finding other test credit card numbers. It appears that Paypal's test card numbers were overused that's why it returned that 'Internal service' or sometimes 'Unknown' error.